# warning: taking address of temporary

Tags: c++

i have the following code snippet

```
if((compare( & key,& ALL))
```

**All** is #defined as

```
#define ALL (some_structure){"ALL", 3}
```

in g++ version

```
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
```

compiled without any warnings

but in g++ version

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
```

it is showing `warning: taking address of temporary`

even though it is a warning.the whole compile message shows aroung 3 million plus messages.It is a legacy code.is there any way to suppress this warning?

**Edit :**

Below is the sample code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct test {   char * name;   int id; }tsTest;

  void print(tsTest * T)   {
    cout<<endl<<"Name :"<<T->name<<endl<<"ID :"<<T->id<<endl;   }

    int main() 
    {   
      print(&(tsTest){"nagaraj",7});   
      return 0; 
    }
```

compiled fine in `g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)`

But in `g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)`

```
temadd.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
temadd.cpp:18: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ 
temadd.cpp:18: warning: taking address of temporary
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. There's some conflicting information and syntactical problems in the code in your question.

Comment: Is it C++? `{|*ALL*|, 7}` you've severely played with operator overloading aren't you?

Comment: like what? it is showing error for ALL (which is #defined structure)

Comment: can you tell me how to suppress the warning..changing the source code is not possible.as there is 3 millions entries

Comment: You tell us you get a warning when you use `ALL` but then show the macro `RT_ALL`?

Comment: sorry..i made the proper edit

Comment: *And* you get the warning because you do something which you should not do. Create a proper variable, and initialize to `ALL` (or `RT_ALL`) and use a pointer to that variable instead. Or if you *save* the pointer, then allocate dynamically. Besides, *why* must you pass a pointer? Can't you change the function to take a constant reference (which can bind to temporaries)?

Comment: function is from third party library

Comment: BTW,  both your versions of GCC are ancient. Consider upgrading to [GCC 5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5) which is conforming to latest C++11 & C++14 standards and probably optimizes better than your old compilers.

Comment: Then depending on how the pointer is used by the function, create an explicit temporary variable and use a pointer to that, or allocate memory for the structure dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can implement `operator&` of the structure. Then you would not take address of the temporary, that is undefined behaviour (*UB*), but calling function of temporary object, returning pointer to itself.

As temporary will live as long as function call, you will not encounter any UB unless you store the pointer and dereference it after leaving the function

For your example it would be like:

```
typedef struct test {
   const char * name;
   int id;
   test* operator&() {
    return this;
   }
}tsTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a warning you should suppress.  The problem with taking the address of a temporary is that when that temporary goes out of scope your application then exhibits undefined behaviour.

Do you have any reason for not defining ALL as a const global?  You could safely take its address at any time without any UB:

```
struct allstruct
{
    char *allname;
    int somenumber;
};

const allstruct ALL { "ALL", 3 };
```

Comment: this is not always the case.i just given a sample eaxmple